# What is a "driver" in a Sylius Resource

Tags: php, symfony, sylius, sylius-resource

[This article](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/configuration.html) mentions "drivers" in the context of a Sylius resource.

> Remember that the doctrine/orm driver is used by default.
>
> You can also configure several doctrine drivers.

```
sylius_resource:
    drivers:
        - doctrine/orm
        - doctrine/phpcr-odm
```

What exactly IS a driver.  I understand, conceptually, this is telling Sylius what sort of model/orm layer my resource uses -- but what do the strings `doctrine/orm` actually do?  Are they packagist packages? Class aliases that resolve to a PHP class name or prefix?  Configuration keys for extra information configured elsewhere? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it relates to the names of the corresponding composer packages and there are currently 3 available options:

- [doctrine/orm](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/orm)
- [doctrine/mongodb-odm](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/mongodb-odm)
- [doctrine/phpcr-odm](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/phpcr-odm)

See also: https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/src/Bundle/SyliusResourceBundle.php#L48-L55

In the future this might be reduced to just doctrine/orm, considering [both odm drivers trigger a deprecation](https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusResourceBundle/blob/master/src/Bundle/DependencyInjection/SyliusResourceExtension.php#L87-L92)

As to what drivers do: A driver provides an ObjectManager and ObjectRepository for resources that will be mapped to the aliases `manager` and `registry`, if I see it correctly.